# How do I find the longest string in a row amongst various text fields?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Does anyone have an easy query to find the longest string of characters in a data row from ALL alphanumeric (text, nchar, varchar, etc) type columns from ALL tables in a single SQL Server 2008 R2 database?

Comment: I am looking for one single number to be returned, as well as the table and column name that contains the string that is found.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following code should return a single column that has the largest piece of text in the current database, along with the Schema, Table, and Column name, and the size of the piece of text:

```
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(max);
DECLARE @sep NVARCHAR(max);
SET @cmd = '';
SET @sep = '';
SELECT @cmd = @cmd + @sep +
    'SELECT ''' + QUOTENAME(sc.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + 
    '.' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ''' AS ColumnName, ' + 
    QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' AS ColumnValue, LEN(CAST(' + 
    QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' AS NVARCHAR(max))) AS ColumnLength ' +
    ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(sc.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name)
    , @sep = ' UNION ALL '   
FROM sys.tables t 
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.types ty on c.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas sc ON t.schema_id = sc.schema_id
WHERE t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND ty.name IN (
        'ntext'
        , 'text'
        , 'varchar'
        , 'nvarchar'
        , 'nchar'
        , 'char'
        , 'sysname'
        , 'sql_variant'
        );
SET @cmd = 'SELECT TOP(1) * FROM (' + @cmd + ') t ORDER BY 3 DESC'
SELECT @cmd; /* This displays the resulting SQL Text that will be 
            EXEC'd by the following statement */
EXEC sp_executesql @cmd;
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll give this a shot as soon as I get to the office this morning.

Comment: What is `@sep` for?

Comment: @sep is used to add the ` UNION ALL ` between each successive `SELECT ...`.  I could hard code it in as `@cmd = @cmd + ' UNION ALL ' + ...` but then I'd end up with an extra `UNION ALL` at the beginning of the string, which would cause a syntax error.

Comment: Oh I was confused because you don't assign a value to @sep until inside the query - I didn't look there. I usually use STUFF to eliminate the first UNION ALL (or comma, or whatever the concatenation is).

Comment: @user1873604 - did this work for you?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Had some fires to put out here before I got a chance to try it.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Out of curiosity, why did you want to find that out?

Comment: Replication. Want to use Peer to Peer. And, the nature of the servers makes it a lot of red tape to change anything at all in the configuration. Wanted to see if in the past we had come close to the default Max text length for replication.

Comment: Cool.  Never thought of that!